# Get instance of class (this) in function inside instance object - typescript/angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, class

I have a separate object that manages a particular dialog box. Consider the following code. As it is very easy to imagine what the functions do, I'm however unable to access the instance of the class. I tried using the traditional `that = this` approach.

```
export class Whatever implements OnInit {

    that = this;

    dialog = {
       data:{},
       open:function() {
           //way to access 'that' variable
       },
       close:function() {},
       toggle:function() {}
    }

    //other declarations and functions
}
```

As my application is scaling, I'm having too many functions inside this service. So i'm trying to club some of these functions into objects, which will make the code much cleaner.

Also if there is any better approach to this, I'd love to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best way would be to replace the `function(){}` with the ES6 arrow functions, which holds your `this` context like so `() => {}`.

You can also use `functions(){}.bind(this)`, but it's much better to just use arrow functions. Both will keep your reference to `this` as expected in the body of the function

Comment: Thanks. +1 for additional `bind(this)` option

Answer (score 1):

You have to use arrow functions to not lose the context(`this`);

```
export class Whatever implements OnInit {   

  dialog = {
     data:{},
     open:() => {
         //'this' will point to Whatever class's instance
     },
     close:() => {},
     toggle:() => {}
  }

  //other declarations and functions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `that` isn't a variable, it's a property of the `Whatever` instance.

Your `dialog` is also a property of the `Whatever` instance. In calls to its methods, `this` will vary depending on how they're called.

To ensure they access the `Whatever` instance, you can use arrow functions and use `this` within the functions:

```
export class Whatever implements OnInit {

    dialog = {
       data: {},
       open: () => {
           // use `this` here
           // use `this.dialog.data` to acccess the data above
       },
       close: () => {},
       toggle: () => {}
    };

    //other declarations and functions
}
```

This works because class fields declared as you've declared them there are effectively initialized as though they were inside your constructor, and within the constructor, `this` refers to the instance. Arrow functions *close over* the `this` of the context where they're created (just like closing over an in-scope variable).